# coldfusion with memcached client returning error after 270 or so calls

Tags: coldfusion, memcached

My question seems to be related to this one:

[Coldfusion memcached connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225948/coldfusion-memcached-connections)

however, i have been unable to solve it.

if i put this code in application.cfm:

```
<cfif not IsDefined("application.memcached")>   
  <cfset application.memcachedFactory = createObject("component","memcachedFactory").init("192.168.2.91:11211")>
  <cfset application.memcached = application.memcachedFactory.getmemcached()>
</cfif>
```

the page will work for maybe 270 calls. then it will start to fail with an error "Object Instantiation Exception " The code is properly talking to memcached. I can send and receive data. it seems like java is running out of something .. threads, sockets, handles of some sort. I know little about java, and am stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems wrong to me Don. Why would this code run again after the very first call? It should be running 1 time after which you have a reference to your object. What does the rest of your application.cfm look like? Have you added a cfapplication tag with a "name"?

If you fail to set an application "name" (via the cfapplication tag or "this.name" in application.cfc), the an "application.x" variable is treated just like a regular variable. After the page request ends it will "go away" and require the next request to reinstantiate the object over again.

The purpose of the "isDefined()" in this case is to insure it runs only once - providing you with a singleton (single reference) you can use again and again without reinstantiating it. It sounds like you are not "inside" an application.

Comment: i did verify that its running multiple times - isDefined is doing nothing. i'll check the application.cfm further.

Comment: it turns out that that the cfapplication tag was AFTER this code. i put it before the code and now its working great

Comment: awesome... I had a feeling :)

Comment: thanks so much for the answer. one "add-on" question ... do you know if future calls to application.memcached.get and set need to be protected by a cflock? not sure how threadsafe the calls are ...

Comment: No you wouldn't want to lock the application scope - that would effectively "single thread" all calls to memcached - sort of defeats the purpose :)